# Combining 2 Images overlayed

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I've got a things to do with android,
so, I have 2 images,
1. image from camera
2. another image from somewhere

so what I want to achieve is how to combine those image into 1 image, but it's overlapping (just like watermarking the image),
the 2nd image should be scaled first into the size of the 1st image(camera) - so they have same dimension, then if the 2nd image pixel is black, don't combine it (so the black means transparent color - on 2nd image)

do you know what is the best way achieve this, can I do this with xor or bitwise?

Any reference or sample code would be really really much appreciate.

Thanks guys,

Comment: http://kyogs.blogspot.in/2012/08/mearge-images.html check this one.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For overlaying two bitmaps:

```
public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

And for scaling one first you should check out createScaledBitmap, e.g:

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, dstWidth, dstHeight, filter);
```

Comment: hi there,Thanks for your reply, I'll try first and get back here with the result

Comment: hi It's work even with the large dimension ~ 2000px x 1500px, but the thing is if i do it twice, the second attempt is got an exception (may be out of synch) - i put your code inside the thread

Comment: @AnD@Cpt.Ohlund: In my device bottomImage(bmp1) is not displaying.Do u know why?Instead of that image some color was displaying.

Comment: Is there any alternate way, this takes too long