# Android: How to solve Bitmap java.lang.OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` when using bitmap to show large images.
 For resizing the bitmap, I referred following link [Save Bitmap and BitmapFactory.decodeFile](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/SaveBitmapandBitmapFactorydecodeFile.htm).

My logcat is as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at     android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at     android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:604)
    at     android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
    at     com.android.restaurant.DescriptionPage.getResizedBitmap(DescriptionPage.java:327)
    at         com.android.restaurant.DescriptionPage.setDetailsIntoLayout(DescriptionPage.java:172)
    at com.android.restaurant.DescriptionPage.onCreate(DescriptionPage.java:101)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1782)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4135)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: There's either something wrong with your code, or the phone doesn't have enough memory. Either way, we can't help you, at least until you post your code.

Comment: @Raman-Mystry - please refer to the "Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently" article below.  If you're still having problems, please 1) post the relevant code, 2) tell us something about your bitmap (like how big it is in h/w and filesize!), 3) tell us how much memory your system has before attempting to load the bitmap

Comment: [Try it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081008/outofmemoryerror-in-game-with-many-small-images/10086141#comment12999643_10086141

It will really help you.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have not posted your code it is hard to know whether there is a bug or probably ineffective code that can be improved.

But generally the JVM memory is limited, so loading of big image can cause `OutOfMemoryError`.  You can try to increase the JVM memory using `-Xmx` option. This is the first and the simplest  way.

Other way is to decrease your image (if it is possible). Or probably use format other than BMP (e.g. JPG). It guarantees good quality and requires less memory.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge in developing mobile application is that you have limited memory.

First thing stuck to my mind is try to use PNG(Portable Network graphics) instead of the BitMaps (if possible).

Apart from that, It seems that this is existing issue please check this:-
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488