# Out of memory error in creating bitmap

Tags: android, performance, out-of-memory

I am getting out of memory errors in my android project and it points to this statement:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Is there any alternate way to create a `ARGB_8888` bitmap which could save me from out of memory errors?

Suggestions appreciated.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: don't use bitmap, use uri

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object

Comment: you can compress the image

Comment: thank u all, I've gone through these links but couldn't figure out how i can modify this statement (Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)).   If I start it this way: BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 8;    what should be the statement to create a bitmap

Comment: @AnyssaK  see my updated answer.

Comment: why down vote?? this is not a duplicate question....

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with memory exceptions with bitmaps on Android, many of which are discussed on stackoverflow. It would probably be best if you went through the existing questions to see if yours matches one of the existing ones, then if not, write up what makes your situation different.

Different Bitmap configurations will have different memory footprints. **RGB_565** is a **16 bit colour** format. **ARGB_8888** is a **32 bit** format.

Regardless of which **getHolder().setFormat();** configuration you've chosen, or how it's being drawn, an **ARGB_8888 Bitmap** is going to be significantly larger (in memory) than a Bitmap in **RGB_565** format.
so Better use **RGB_565** format instead of **ARGB_8888**.

Some examples:

[Out of memory exception due to large bitmap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321579/out-of-memory-exception-due-to-large-bitmap-size)

[Android: out of memory exception in Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238388/android-out-of-memory-exception-in-gallery)

[Android handling out of memory exception on image processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724082/android-handling-out-of-memory-exception-on-image-processing)

etc : [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+out+of+memory+exception+bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android%20out%20of%20memory%20exception%20bitmap)

For more detail visit here. [android - out of memory exception when creating bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697760/android-out-of-memory-exception-when-creating-bitmap)

Comment: I am trying to create a blank canvas using bitmap with following 2 statements: obBitmapBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(obWidth, obHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); obCanvasBuffer = new Canvas(obBitmapBuffer); Can someone please help, how can I do it. (I reffered above mentioned links, but that doesnt ghelps)

Comment: thanks Harshad, I just tried with RGB_565, it's affecting the animations UI which is not acceptable :( Any other clues?

Comment: @AnyssaK  you can make the Bitmap scale down and then Use it.It will also solve the problem.