# Merge two bitmaps(png) with code

Tags: android, bitmap

In my android app.
I want to merge  two images to produce one so i can use.

**this is what i have**

\n

I have [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tkcm4n2zd20bofq/Photo%206-9-16%2C%2010%2002%2051%20PM.png?dl=0) image

*i want to merge it with another image in each place*
So the result will be [like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3scrasmg9csarwu/Photo%206-9-16%2C%2010%2026%2025%20PM.png?dl=0)
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you post the code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Didn't try anything cause I'm new to programming

Comment: Maybe some lead me to tutorial or some thing

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674441/combining-2-images-overlayed) sounds similar to what you are looking for.

Basically you need to create a Bitmap, create a Canvas, then draw each image on the canvas.  I'm not positive how they will work as being PNG's and being able to see both images, but this is how I've drawn multiple images into one.  I would guess that you draw each image starting at the same position (unlike the way I did it).

Hope this helps.

```
result = Bitmap.createBitmap((bmImages[0].getWidth() * 2) + 45, (bmImages[0].getHeight()) + 30, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
for (int i = 0; i < bmImages.length; i++) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmImages[i], (bmImages[i].getWidth() * (i % 2)) + ((i+1)*15), 15, null);
    bmImages[i].recycle();
}
```